# CURL multi interface can resolve host

Tags: curl, dns, resolve

Regarding curl 7.47.0 on linux Ubuntu multi interface , using the example code at :
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/asiohiper.html
(with one small change which causes it to repeatedly fetch the initial URL)

If DNS is configured before i run the example everything works as expected. If DNS is not configured (/etc/resolv.conf is empty) , when i run the example then i get
CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST which is expected. But if i setup DNS (which populates /etc/resolv.conf) while the program is still running , it still fails with CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST. I've tried everything including calling curl_multi_cleanup and then curl_multi_init again before starting a new download , but nothing helps. It seems like the library is sticking with the initial DNS configuration (which was empty). Any idea how to force the library to use the new DNS entries which were added after it started ?

Answer (score 0):

i think i found the problem. nothing to do with CURL. this is the solution:
[Using glibc, why does my gethostbyname fail after I/DHCP has changed the DNS server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125466/using-glibc-why-does-my-gethostbyname-fail-after-i-dhcp-has-changed-the-dns-ser)